# I would like to get list of installed programs as shown in Add/Remove Programs of the control panel

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I would like to get list of installed programs as shown in Add/Remove Programs of the control panel using C sharp

I know using `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall (32bit)` or `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall (64bit)` can get program names but how to get its exe file name?

Example `MS Word` is the program name which the above mentioned registers help me to get but its application file is `winword.exe`. I need to get this information so that I can start those applications through the code

Edited:
I need to to get the list of installed programs along with their exe information so that when user selects that program name from my application I should be able to trigger that application

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: How to get installing programs exactly like in control panel programs and features?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524161/c-how-to-get-installing-programs-exactly-like-in-control-panel-programs-and-fe)

Comment: Don't think that's possible as what you install is a `software package` not a `program (single exe file)`

Comment: @Ankur; Don't say that not possible. (Its possible but a little harder to achieve it. I shall post the answer soon when I get it. I am almost close to achieve it.). I din't knew that its a software package, i was thinking it was single program(single exe) :-P

Thanks for your answer

Comment: The problem would be to verify that the solution you come up works with all the software packages available for window ;)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Add/Remove does not contain that kind of information.
Let's take Office as an example, you install a whole package, having excel.exe, winword.exe among others.
What you could do, is cross that information with the one available from the Start Menu, where most of the shortcuts are.
Most people don't delete the Start Menu shortcuts, so maybe it is an option.
Another one, would be to read the installation folder and filter out every .exe

Check this for executing lnk: [c# memory usage for starting lnk shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532713/c-sharp-memory-usage-for-starting-lnk-shortcuts)

Comment: if you take installation folder and filter our exe files there are cases where more than one exe file present.

Comment: That's right, so reading the shortcuts may be the best option?

Comment: ok, then how can i trigger an application through shortcut. should i open it with the help of explorer and open it??

Comment: Check this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532713/c-sharp-memory-usage-for-starting-lnk-shortcuts